# Facebook sdk key hash too short

Tags: android, windows, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0, boringssl

I recently tried to integrate the facebook-sdk into one of my Unity projects, the implementation process went fine however in order to make use of the facebook-sdk api's I need to generate a key-hash (debug and release).

I tried it with cmd since this seems to be the most easy way, however when generating the key-hash I run into a problem, because the key-hash is not 28-letters long.

1. I downloaded openssl from here: code.google.com (openssl-0.9.8k_X64.zip)
2. I open cmd and typed in this command:

   **keytool -exportcert -alias *mykeyalias* -keystore *PathToKeystore\MyKey.keystore* | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64**
3. I then need to input the password of keystore-file
4. Finally I get a key-hash, but it's too short:
   [Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMxuz.png)

However what is weird is: when I input this command in cmd:
    **keytool -exportcert -alias *mykeyalias* -keystore *PathToKeystore\MyKey* | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64**

So instead of "MyKey.keystore" just "MyKey", I do not have to input my password and I actually do get an 28-letters-hash:
[Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoYmc.png)

Can anybody explain me what causes this?

Answer (score 3):

The same thing happened to me because I was using openssl-0.9.8k_X64.zip instead of openssl-0.9.8e_X64.zip.

https://code.google.com/archive/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads